# sudo doesn't work on ro filesystems

Tags: filesystem, sudo

When for whatever reason my home partitions gets mounted read-only, sudo fails:

```
/usr/bin/sudo: Input/output error
```

From what I understand, it seems to be trying to touch `~/.sudo_as_admin_successful`

Is there a way around this, to use sudo to remount my harddisk?
Should I file a bug?

Answer (score 0):

If the filesystem were read only the error message would say so.  This seems to be because there is an underlying problem with your disk.  You should investigate the cause of that with `dmesg`.

Comment: Other binaries in /usr/bin work. Anyother attempts to change the file system complain about a read-only filesystem. I think that the issue with the disk is that the connector is faulty. But IMO sudo should be able to work even so.

Comment: @nishantjr, yes, it looks like you have a hardware problem that is is throwing IO errors in some places, including when trying to read `sudo`.  A side effect of the IO errors is that the fs gets remounted read-only.  You need to fix your hardware problem.